# I just start learn lua in windows,i set LUA_INIT as lua -e "print('ss')",this cmd work in cmd line but do not work after i set the verible LUA_INI

Tags: lua, environment-variables

this is the value of LUA_INIT_5_3:
[image: 1]

this is the error information
[image: 2]

Comment: Please don't use images.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 7 - Lua Standalone](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7)

> When called without option -E, the interpreter checks for an
> environment variable LUA_INIT_5_3 (or LUA_INIT if the versioned name
> is not defined) before running any argument. If the variable content
> has the format @filename, then lua executes the file. Otherwise, lua
> executes the string itself.

Your environment variable is not of the format @filename so Lua executes `lua -e "print('ss')"` which of course is invalid Lua syntax and hence causes an error.

Either reduce the content of your environment variable to `print('ss')` or put that into a file and provide that file's name through your variable.